# Train autoencoder on 1D data with high and low amplitudes

Tags: autoencoder

I'm using an autoencoder-RNN combination to predict colliding waves in 1D. The training data is obtained by using the 1D Euler equations along with boundary conditions to preduce to waves (left and right) that will collide somewhere in the middle. To get a wide range of training data the boundary conditions for the Euler equations are varied, resulting in different amplitudes and widths of the waves.

The problem here is that some waves have small amplitudes and others have large amplitudes. When train the autoencoder on the normalised data set it will mainly learn how to reproduce the large amplitudes but fails to reproduce or poorly reproduces the small amplitudes.

I'm currently using an MSE loss function to train the autoencoder. Is this the best way to do it for my case or might another loss function perform better?